# How do I update a datatable from a commandbutton press?

Tags: java, jsf, datatable, ejb

I have a jsf page that succesfully pulls data from my data bean when the page first loads.

What I want is for the datatable to use text input from a inputText component in the jsf, and then use that within the call the jsf bean and generate the table.

How would I go about doing this?

Specifically what I want is

- Take text input from inputText JSF component
- On commandButton JSF component click
- Update the dataTable using the inputText as a parameter with the bean call

  ```
      <h:dataTable value="#{movie.getSearchMovieList('car')}" var="c"
                   styleClass="order-table"
                   headerClass="order-table-header"
                   rowClasses="order-table-odd-row,order-table-even-row"
                   >

          <h:column>
              <f:facet name="header">
                  Movie ID
              </f:facet>
              #{c.itemid}
          </h:column>

          <h:column>
              <f:facet name="header">
                  Title
              </f:facet>
              #{c.title}
          </h:column>
      </h:dataTable>
  ```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a field in the managed bean to hold the default value when navigating:

```
private String filter = "car"; // + getter/setter
```

Then, in the view:

```
<h:form>
    <h:inputText label="Type search filter :" value="#{movie.filter}" />
    <h:dataTable value="#{movie.getSearchMovieList(movie.filter)}" var="c" ... >
        ...
    </h:dataTable>

    <h:commandButton value="Search" /> // no action attribute means refreshing
<h:form>
```

Comment: Excellent, thank you. Simple, concise and effective.

Comment: You don't need to pass the `movie.filter` through the method. It automatically sets it in `value`. Just food for thought when you have many variables...